# Amazon RDS Postgresql not assigning primary key

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I did a migration from a Postgresql database that was on EC2 to an RDS instance using Amazon's database migration tool.

My application uses sqlalchemy on Python 3.4. Since the migration, attempts to add new data to the database result in an error `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

I checked the database in pg_admin and it shows `ALTER TABLE public.users ADD COSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);` as a users_pkey constraint on the table.

The application is able to read data and modify existing data without error.

Comment: That's not what you need for it to be auto-assigned.  Is there a default value?

Comment: No, and it worked previously without a default value. The column is `id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)`

The option to index is redundant, but the code specifying the column has been unchanged, and primary keys were assigned previously

Comment: Can you check if the "old" database had a default value?  In my experience PostgreSQL is exactly the same in the AWS RDS environment as it is locally or on an EC2.  We use scripts to create the databases locally and on RDS and they "just work".  I feel like something else that is missing.

Comment: Nice suggestion... a lot of stuff is missing.

Old EC2 db has `ALTER TABLE public.users ADD COLUMN id integer; ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL; ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass);`

I'm also missing all of my foreign keys. I need to figure out what went wrong with the DMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stdunbar pointed me in the right direction on this, thank you.

I'm not sure if this is a complete "answer" but it took a good amount of time to figure out a solution to the problem.

@studunbar pointed me to look at what was reflected on the RDS database. The docs imply this, but it eluded me - DMS doesn't copy over any sequences, indices, or foreign key relationships. I tried to use the schema migration tool to do this after the fact and it just wiped out my data. Using before prevented my migration scripts from running.

Likely this is user error. But my fix was to use pg_dump and pg_restore to migrate, bypassing DMS completely. I realize this is only applicable to PostgreSQL.

In fairness, the AWS docs do briefly suggest using native tools when possible.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! In PGAdmin I looked under the "sequences" section and can see that nothing is there for the new DB

Comment: How do you actually migrate the data? Did you use pg_dump on the original database? How does that migrate it to the new one?